# "Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application" in maven application

Tags: java, maven, javafx

I am trying to add JavaFX to my project in java, as I want to switch from java swing. The project was not a maven project, but I created a pom.xml file. I am using Intellij as my IDE, and it prompted me to load maven scripts, at which point it made a .iml file too.

I added the necessary dependencies to pom.xml, and java seemed to find all the imports I needed. Whenever I run the application though, I get **"Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application"**.

This is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>your.group.id</groupId>
    <artifactId>your-artifact-id</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>21</source>
                    <target>21</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-base</artifactId>
            <version>19.0.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>19.0.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-graphics </artifactId>
            <version>19.0.2.1</version>
            <classifier>win</classifier>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>19.0.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
            <version>19.0.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-media</artifactId>
            <version>19.0.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-swing</artifactId>
            <version>19.0.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I did also try adding this plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.8</version>
    <configuration>
        <mainClass>src/org.Chess.App</mainClass>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

But that didn't seem to do anything.

My project structure in case that helps:

[image]

I am sure I am making some stupid mistake and I know that making a javaFX project from the start with intellij would be easier, but I would ideally just add the library to this existing project without modifying the structure or making a new one. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Follow the direction here -> https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/

Comment: As you are using Idea, you can also create a [new JavaFX project in Idea](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/javafx.html), then copy your code into it.  That is what I would recommend (even though you state you don't want to make a new project).  When copying the code across, follow the [standard directory layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) (not what you currently have).

Comment: Some other random advice. Don't put unnecessary classifiers like `win` in your dependencies unless you really know what you are doing with them (it would break stuff if you aren't using windows).  Use a recent stable version of JavaFX (e.g. 20.0.1).  You don't need to list transitive dependencies like javafx-base unless you are using classifiers.  You don't need web and media dependencies if you aren't using those modules (same for swing). `src/org.Chess.App` is not your main class.  That is saying look for the class App in the package org.Chess in the module src, which all seems wrong.

Comment: Also study [javafx modules](https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html), because a lot of people new to JavaFX don't really understand modules and that ends up causing them a lot of problems.